# Make Check Page Reverse Proxy Nginx | Like Cloudflare's I'm Under Attack Mode

Tags: perl, nginx, proxy

I have a large server with DDoS protection. I also have a setup for stopping layer 7 attacks.

I want to set up a reverse proxy to my website on my other server and have a check page similar to cloudflare's I'm Under Attack Mode.

Which only after displaying that check page and passing the check will the nginx reverse proxy pass the request onto my other server with the website.

There is absolutely ZERO documentation on this.

I have found https://index.hm/hashcat.html although there is many problems with this as you need perl modules. Which apt-get install nginx-extras doesn't have.

I am just looking for some guidance, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This question would probably be better on ServerFault (but I can't move it as I don't have enough rep)

HashCat isn't really production-ready software, but as its developer I can give you an overview on how to prepare your server for it:

It needs the `ngx_http_perl_module` module to run correctly, as I think you identified. As far as I'm aware, though, Debian does not compile nginx with the embedded Perl module by default. I think Red Hat does though, if it makes your life any easier.

You can activate the module by building nginx with the flag `--with-http_perl_module`.

Check out https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingAPackage#Get_the_source_package for a guide on compiling Debian packages - I've summarised it here for you.

`apt-get install build-essentials`
`apt-get source nginx`
`sudo mk-build-deps -i -r nginx`
`cd nginx-xxxx`
`nano debian/rules`

Add the configure flag "--with-http_perl_module" to the file. Now, we can recompile the package and produce a new .deb file

`debuild -us -uc`

Install the .deb

`sudo dpkg -i ../nginx-xxxxx.deb`

This should replace the nginx you have installed with a Perl-enabled version :-)

(P.S. Don't forget to run `cpan Digest::SHA1 String::Util`)

And to install HashCat, make a folder /usr/share/nginx/perl (if it doesn't already exist) and place the source files in it.